# MOve scroll according the record in repeater

Tags: asp.net

In my webform I have a repeater control. I have a button to open pop Up also. This pop up contains all records which are coming up in the parent window. On selecting the record I have to move the scrollbar of parent window for the location of the record.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to move the scrollbar in two cases.

1. window scroll
2. Repeater in div

   repeater.item[0].focus();

Answer (score 0):

If your popup have fixed position and you do not support IE7 and less you can use simple link anchoring:

```
records/#record1
```

where `record1` is ID of the record header or container. In this case browser will focus on the target element and your popup will stay with fixed position.

Also, you can use jQuery for it. You can get position of the target eleemnt and then scroll window to this position. Here is example of scrolling: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

```
<div id="record1"></div>
<div id="record2"></div>
<div id="record3"></div>
```

and links should be like

```
<a href="#record1">record1</a>
<a href="#record2">record2</a>
<a href="#record3">record3</a>
```

Comment: My repeater control is inside the div. what to to for this /